# Understanding the difference between "Response Headers" and "Request Headers" in Firefox Developer Console (network tab) for image cache control

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

> **Edit: I found out my problem. I was using the network inspector wrong (in both Chrome and FF) -- basically I was clicking "refresh"
>   and watching the network inspector, but it would re-download
>   everything. What you need to do is go to the URL, then open the network inspector, *then go to the URL
>   again* ( Don't "refresh", just re-access the URL a second time). The
>   network inspector will notify you of which resources were pulled from
>   cache :)**

***Original question below:***

I am trying to set the image cache settings in Apache. I have the following in **.htaccess** for 1 week image caching:

```
FileETag MTime Size

ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>
```

This looks correct when I check the network tab of the Firefox developer console, but I don't understand why the **Request Header** says "no-cache"

Note: I removed the lines that do not matter for this question.

[image: Firefox Developer console network response headers]

I am also serving some images dynamically with PHP. I have caching for those images set for 2 days, but again, the response header says "no-cache". Is this anything to worry about? The images do not appear to be cached when I refresh Firefox. They look like they are being redownloaded:

[image: network response of PHP dynamic images]

Any help understanding these headers would be appreciated. If there is an easy way to determine if images are being pulled from cache or not, I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Pragma` and `Cache-Control` request headers mean the same thing, one's from HTTP 1.0 and the other is from 1.1. It's used to tell the server, or a proxy that does caching, that it wants fresh versions of the resource. It's NOT for telling the server that the browser won't cache, or that the browser won't be honoring the cache control the server responds with.

Ultimately, the server can tell a user agent "Here's the resource, cache it for 1 week", but it's still up to the user agent (e.g. browser) to honor that. It could always request the uncached version of the resoure every time instead of not sending the request and loading the locally cached copy.

Comment: So in my examples above, when my request headers say "no-cache", does that mean the resources were not cached? Or does it simply mean "I am requesting a new version of this resource (if available)"? When I visit other websites I am seeing a similar pattern for both the request and response headers, but I want to be sure this looks normal.

Comment: @degenerate If the request is made at all, that means it wasn't cached, or the user agent wanted a new copy. If the browser was going to use a cached version, the request wouldn't even have been made.